# why I can't change toolbar title after using back button (physical back button) in Android?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

here is the project to be downloaded: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lq3p2pnwjacik7s/testApp.zip?dl=0

I am using Android navigation component, and here is the screenshot of the app:

[image]

as you can see, in the MainActivity layout, there are a nav_host_fragment, a toolbar and a bottom navigation view.

and the sequence of Blue Tab will be like this in the graph

[image]

the title in the toolbar "CUSTOM TITLE HERE" is hard coded in the destination_blue1 fragment

but when I move from blue1 to blue2, and then go back to blue1 using back button (physhical hardware back button), the title then change to "fragment_blue1", not "CUSTOM TITLE HERE" (hard coded).

"fragment_blue1"  is actually string of destination graph id of that fragment.

I don't understand why even though I have hard coded the title to be  "CUSTOM TITLE HERE", it just doesn't work if I use (physhical hardware back button).

but if I use up button (back button in the toolbar/actionbar) then the title will be "CUSTOM TITLE HERE" as per the title that I hard code.

here is the title when my hard coded title doesn't work, when I move from blue 2 back to blue1 using back button(physical back button).

[image]

this is the simplification of my real case, I need to change the title dynamically from fragment Blue1. I don't understand why I can't change the title after using back button. but when using up button, the title will follow as per the code I use, not the same as destination id graph.

how to solve this ? what went wrong ?

I am using style `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` and here is the code of my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var navController : NavController
    lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    lateinit var bottomNavigationView : BottomNavigationView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        setUpViewDeclaration()
        setupBottomNavMenu()
        setupActionBar()


    }

    private fun setUpViewDeclaration() {
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav)

    }

    private fun setupBottomNavMenu() {
        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    private fun setupActionBar() {

        // set up top hierarchy destination
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.destination_blue1,
            R.id.destination_red1)
        )

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)

    }
}
```

here is the code of blue1 fragment

```
class Blue1Fragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var moveButton: Button
    lateinit var fragmentView: View

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue1, container, false)
        moveButton = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.move_button_1)

        // The title hard coded in here
        // this one line below seems doesn't work if using back physical button
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "CUSTOM TITLE HERE" 



        moveButton.setOnClickListener {

            val nextDestination = Blue1FragmentDirections.actionToBlue2()
            Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigate(nextDestination)

        }

        return fragmentView
    }


}
```

here is the code of blue2 fragment:

```
class Blue2Fragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue2, container, false)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try set the title in "onViewCreated"

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I have tried to move it to onResume as well, but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you adding fragment, while adding onResume not invoking. If your navigation is straightforward (routing between fragments always the same) you can implement it by calling onStop() in SecondFragment and inside this method change toolbar title to the first fragment title.
If your fragments changes dynamically (from fr1 call fr2/fr3) you can pass title on bundle and replace it with your custom title

```
//inside Blue2Fragment

override fun onStop() {
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "CUSTOM TITLE HERE"
    super.onStop()
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I have tried to put that onStop code in Blue2Fragment :(

Comment: @Alexa289 when you close Blue2Fragment onStop invokes and here u can set title before destroying fragment, I think that u implement in in first fragment, or try onPause too, but it will not make any sense. I've tried my case and it works well

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. it should be implemented right this, right ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaFHr.png . if yes, then unfortunately it still doesn't work. the title still not "CUSTOM TITLE HERE" if I use back button (physical back button in the right bottom). if you don't mind, you can download the project above via my dropbox link :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `kotlin`, but here comes a workaround in `java` that solves this issue, by changing the `toolbar`'s `title` and `subTitle` dynamically.

First, we need to create an object to be used as `MultableLiveData` type with title and subtitle parameters.

```
public class Toolbar {
    private String title, subTitle;

    public Toolbar(String title, @Nullable String subTitle) {
        this.title = title;
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getSubTitle() {
        return subTitle;
    }
}
```

In `MainActivity`, we define `toolbar` as `MultableLiveData` and observe it in `onCreate()` and remove the observer in `onDestroy()`.

```
public MutableLiveData<Toolbar> toolbar = new MutableLiveData<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_bottomnav);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_sidebar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer);

    setupNavigation();

    toolbar.observe(this, new Observer<Toolbar>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Toolbar toolbarModel) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(toolbarModel.getTitle());
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(toolbarModel.getSubTitle());
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    toolbar.removeObservers(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

In any of your fragments, we set the `toolbar`s title and subtitle as follow:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).toolbar.postValue(new Toolbar("MyFragment Title", "MyFragment SubTitle"));
}
```

Or

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).toolbar.postValue(new Toolbar("MyFragment Title", null));
}
```

Also remove `android:label` from your `nav_graph.xml` to avoid title/label conflicts.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/shopFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.ShopFragment"
    android:label="TO BE REMOVED" // REMOVE THIS LINE OF CODE
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_shop" />
```

I hope it helps!